# Drive By Wire Without Adaptive Cruise Control

Tags: nissan

I have a 2014 Nissan Rouge Select, however I do not have the adaptive cruise control option, rather only the regular cruise control, with switches to control speed and braking.

I read that Nissan has put [drive-by-wire](https://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/a8116/nissan-will-put-drive-by-wire-in-2013-cars-13818193/) in all production cars since 2013.

Does this mean that the steering in my 2014 Rouge without any ADAS, can be controlled by wire?

If so, how?

Comment: Might just be the accelerator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at available parts for the Rogue (I've seen a few Rogues with the lettering rearranged on the tailgate to spell Rouge), it still has the conventional arrangement almost all small vehicles have now - a conventional rack without any power assistance, and a shaft linkage to the column that incorporates the electric power assistance motor at the bottom. Although the lane following and possibly other driver assistance systems can steer the vehicle using the EPAS motor, it turns the column complete including the steering wheel. So no, it's not drive by wire. Because of the safety implications with a failure of a true drive by wire system, they're pretty expensive to implement, with redundant motors and sensors needed.

You should be able to verify this simply by turning the steering wheel with the engine off - with no power to the system, the mechanical linkage will still turn the wheels - though you'll find it hard to turn while stationary with no assistance.

Comment: Thanks Phil, makes sense!  Is there any way to send commands to this EPAS motor over the CAN bus?

Comment: Hackers have controlled steering on some vehicles over CAN, but I suspect that it involves far more than sending commands, there'd likely be some security around the system - or at least there should be.